# how to trace system clock

Tags: java, time, system

i am beginner in java. i have create one application which is used to trace the time of the work

there is 2 functionality 1.start time and 2.stop time when user i have to count that time and give the difference between that times and store it.

i have trying all the search engines but i don't get proper word to find it

but problem is that if user start the timer and then change system time update with more time then my output is wrong

now what i have to do for this problem? is there any way to detect the system time changes?

Comment: Can you clarify this sentence?"but problem is that if user start the timer and then change system time update with more time then my output is wrong". What do you mean by "change system time update"? Do you refer to "daylight time change" or to the admin adjusting the system time? What accuracy do you need? How long are the common tasks you must measure?

Comment: if user start timer at that time the system time is 3:51 then start time is 3:51 now user change system time and do it 6:15 nad press stop then he got the ending time 6:15 because system time is change now

Answer (score 0):

You can use **google-guava** library class [**Stopwatch**](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html)
example

```
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch().start();  
...
long passedMillis = s.stop().elapsedMillis();
```

works as expected if user change system time.

*Maven dependency*

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
     <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
     <version>11.0.2</version>
     <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
```

Or you can use **apache-commons** lib class [**StopWatch**](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html)
example

```
  StopWatch s = new StopWatch();
  s.start();
  ...
  s.stop();
  long passedMillis = s.getTime();
```

*Maven dependency*

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to solve your problem:

1)Prevent system time change:

This is easy if the machines are corporate machines controlled by a system administrator and the users do not have administrator rights. 
Since changing the time requires some advanced user permissions the user will not be able to change system time. The "official" time change as it is planned and known when happens can be considered in your calculations.

2)Monitor system time:
You can monitor system time change by having a thread that is comparing system time with the previous read system time. If there is a sudden unexpected change you can detect the user is cheating.

In this same thread, you can have some kind of "ellapsed time" counter that every second updates a counter. This way, no matter if the user changes time, you will be updating your "ellapsed time counter" and using it to calculate the task duration not system time.

Answer (score 0):

> But problem is that if user start the timer and then change system
> time update with more time then my output is wrong.

Under linux you are safe to use `System.getNanoTime()`, as it uses `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` as clock source. That will only work if the system is NOT RE-BOOTET between taking the start time and the end time.

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is a clock source that can not be altered. It gets initialized to an arbitrary value when the system boots up. This clock will only increment in a constant way. There are no jumps.
It is very useful to measure time, as it is independent to the system's wall time (the time you see on your pc's clock) and very accurate.

I just took a look at the source of openjdk-7-b147.

In `hotspot\src\os\linux\vm\os_linux.cpp`

```
jlong os::javaTimeNanos() {
  if (Linux::supports_monotonic_clock()) {
    struct timespec tp;
    int status = Linux::clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);
    assert(status == 0, "gettime error");
    jlong result = jlong(tp.tv_sec) * (1000 * 1000 * 1000) + jlong(tp.tv_nsec);
    return result;
  } else {
    timeval time;
    int status = gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    assert(status != -1, "linux error");
    jlong usecs = jlong(time.tv_sec) * (1000 * 1000) + jlong(time.tv_usec);
    return 1000 * usecs;
  }
}
```

[clock_gettime man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime):

> **CLOCK_MONOTONIC**
>
> Clock that cannot be set and represents monotonic time since some
> unspecified starting point.

I no't know how it works on windows, but i *guess* that the used clock source is also not depending on a wall clock.

[This blog post](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.co.at/2012/02/what-is-behind-systemnanotime.html) might be helpful.